# A relation of convergence in Hilbert scheme to convergence in sense of currents

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, complex-manifolds, hilbert-schemes

Let $\{X_i\}$ be a sequence of closed irreducible $k$-dimensional subvarieties of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $d$ (they may be assumed to be smooth if necessary). Assume that this sequence converges to a closed subscheme $X\subset \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ in the sense of the analytic topology on the set of complex points of the Hilbert scheme of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$.

As it follows from a comment to  [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264347/limit-of-a-sequence-of-smooth-varieties-in-hilbert-scheme), every irreducible component of $X$ is $k$-dimensional. Hence we can attach to $X$ a cycle 
$$[X]=\sum_a n_a[Z_a],$$
where $Z_a$ are all irreducible components of $X$ and $n_a\in \mathbb{N}$.

**Question.** Do $\{[X_i]\}$ converge to $[X]$ in the sense of currents? More explicitly, let $\omega$ be any smooth differential $2k$-form on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$. Is it true that 
$$\lim_{i\to\infty}\int_{X_i}\omega=\sum_an_a\int_{Z_a}\omega?$$

A reference would be helpful.

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180933/different-notions-of-convergence-of-complex-subvarieties?rq=1

Comment: It is very similar. The difference is that now the limit scheme does not have to be reduced as it was assumed previously.

Comment: But it doesn't look to me like the answers given in the comments require reducedness of the limit?

Comment: @RuadhaíDervan: It is hard to say from the answers there. It is not explicit there, and I would prefer to have an explicit answer. Do you claim that my question here has a positive answer?

Comment: I am not an expert, but it seems to me that it does (it follows from properties of the Hilb to Chow morphism, which is basically that flat convergence implies convergence as cycles). I will leave it to someone else to give a more definitive reference.